# Not sure about Tkinter class structure and layout

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I am starting by making a simple prompt window where the user will fill out the name of the directory to grab images from and where to save a resultant .csv file (and some other info).

After pressing enter in this (in this case) I want this prompt window to close and the main window where all the work will be performed by the user to appear.

In short, is this the correct way to begin structuring the classes for my GUI? Also why does the line:

```
frame = Frame(master, height=500,padx=20, pady=20)
```

Not change the formatting/layout of this initial window?

I feel that once i have a solid grasp on how to build this initial window, I will have the proper foundation to continue the rest on my own.

```
#imports
from Tkinter import *
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#end imports

class prompt_window:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master, height=500,padx=20, pady=20)

        #Build prompt window labels
        self.source_label = Label(root, text="Source Directory")
        self.destination_label = Label(root, text="Destination Directory")
        self.region_sz_label = Label(root, text="Region Size")
        self.save_file_name_label = Label(root, text="Save File Name")

        #Build prompt window entry forms
        self.source_entry = Entry(root)
        self.destination_entry = Entry(root)
        self.region_sz_entry = Entry(root)
        self.save_file_name_entry = Entry(root)

        #Build enter button
        self.enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter")

        #Align labels in prompt window grid
        self.source_label.grid(row=0)
        self.destination_label.grid(row=1)
        self.region_sz_label.grid(row=2)
        self.save_file_name_label.grid(row=3)

        #Align entry forms in prompt window grid
        self.source_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.destination_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.region_sz_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.save_file_name_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

        #Add button
        self.enter_button.grid(row=4,column=2)

#create root
root = Tk()

#create prompt window
prompt = prompt_window(root)

#run indefinitely
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You will need to call `.grid()` on the `frame` and it should probably be the first argument to the other widgets instead of `root`. The name of the class should be changed to `PromptWindow` to be in accordance with [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @martineau could you explain why .grid() should be called on frame and how it relates to maintaining proper structure?

Comment: **If your code works as expected without any errors** and you want suggestions on performance or your code, you can post a question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Of course before posting please read their tour page.

Comment: @Lafexlos This code doesn't work as intended: it doesn't display the widgets. And the OP doesn't know how to organize things so that the main window opens after the prompt window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call one of the layout methods (`.pack`, `.grid`, or `.place`) on your Frame to make it visible. In my version of your program I've changed the class name from prompt_window to PromptWindow to conform to the PEP-8 style guide. I've also changed the Tkinter import statement so we aren't cluttering our namespace with all those Tkinter names.

Organizing GUI code is a little different to organizing a plain CLI program. Once we've defined everything we sit in a loop waiting for events to respond to. So for this program we need to set things up so that when the prompt window closes the main window opens and it has access to the data gathered by the prompt window.

You said that you want the prompt window to be a different window to the main window, so we need to create a window for it. A Tkinter program can only have one root window, so we create a Toplevel window to hold the prompt Frame.

You don't need to save the Labels as attributes of the PromptWindow instance since you aren't doing anything with them after you create them.

I've changed the Entry widgets slightly: I've given each of them a StringVar to hold their data. This makes it possible to access that data after the prompt window is closed. When a widget's parent window is closed you can't access it anymore. So instead of saving each Entry as an attribute of PromptWindow we instead save the associated StringVar.

When the "Enter" button is pressed or the prompt window's close widget is pressed we close the prompt window and make the main window visible.

I've created a simple MainWindow class that contains a button that lets us print the data gathered by the prompt window.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class PromptWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.win = tk.Toplevel(master)
        self.win.title("Prompt Window")

        # Intercept close window events so that when the user closes this window 
        # (via the close widget or the Enter button) the main window reopens
        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)

        frame = tk.Frame(self.win, height=500,padx=20, pady=20)
        frame.pack()

        # Build prompt window labels
        tk.Label(frame, text="Source Directory").grid(row=0)
        tk.Label(frame, text="Destination Directory").grid(row=1)
        tk.Label(frame, text="Region Size").grid(row=2)
        tk.Label(frame, text="Save File Name").grid(row=3)

        # Build prompt window entry widgets
        self.source = tk.StringVar() 
        tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.source).grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.destination = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.destination).grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.region_sz = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.region_sz).grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.save_file_name = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.save_file_name).grid(row=3, column=1)

        # Build enter button
        tk.Button(frame, text="Enter", command=self.close).grid(row=4,column=2)

    def close(self):
        # Close this window
        self.win.destroy()
        # Reopen the main window
        self.master.deiconify()

class MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Create root window
        root = tk.Tk()
        # and make it invisible
        root.withdraw()
        root.title("Main Window")

        # Add some widgets
        tk.Label(root, text="This is the main window").pack()
        tk.Button(root, text="Show data", command=self.show_data).pack()

        # Create prompt window
        self.prompt = PromptWindow(root)

        # Loop forever
        root.mainloop()

    # Display the data gathered by the prompt window
    def show_data(self):
        prompt = self.prompt
        src = prompt.source.get()
        dest = prompt.destination.get()
        region = prompt.region_sz.get()
        fname = prompt.save_file_name.get()

        fmt = 'src: {!r}, dest: {!r}, region: {!r}, fname: {!r}'
        print(fmt.format(src, dest, region, fname)) 

MainWindow()
```